# conditional match and return values in r

Tags: r, duplicates, match

I have two tables named A and B. There are 300k rows in B. Just one row in a.
I want to generate a table C based on if there is a value in B match value in A for each row.
If it is, return 1; If is not, return 0;
Finally, get a matrix C, which includes (0, 1) with the same row as B.
I use the Match function in excel, but my data is too large. Can realize it in R?

A:

```
A01B A01C A01D A01E A01F A01G
```

B:

```
id1 a A01C  NA    NA    NA 
id2 b A01C A01D   NA    NA
id3 c B01C B03D   NA    NA
id4 d A01F A01F  A01F   NA
...
```

C:

```
A01B A01C A01D A01E A01F A01G
 0    1     0    0    0    0
 0    1     1    0    0    0
 0    0     0    0    0    0
 0    0     0    0    1    0
```

Comment: How is B a table? row 1 seems to have 3 columns but the rest have 4? or is the last column in row 1 blank? Will there only ever be 4 columns in B?

Comment: I edit B in the main question. Actually, B has 28 columns, but most of them are NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this; here is one I can think of. (There is probably something super slick and efficient but I think for 300k rows this will be OK).

First convert your code into a reproducible example.

Here `A` is a vector in R (read yours in as necessary and coerce to vector)

```
A <- c("A01B", "A01C", "A01D", "A01E", "A01F", "A01G")
```

I'm using the `data.table` package here because I like its syntax. You will need to make your B a data.table not just a data.frame

```
library(data.table)

# I used dput(B) to get this command to create a reproducible example
B <- data.table(structure(list(col1 = c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"), col2 = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d"), col3 = c("A01C", "A01C", "B01C", "A01F"), col4 = c(NA, 
"A01D", "B03D", "A01F"), col5 = c(NA, NA, NA, "A01F"), col6 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)))

#      col1   col2   col3   col4   col5   col6
#    <char> <char> <char> <char> <char> <char>
# 1:    id1      a   A01C   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 2:    id2      b   A01C   A01D   <NA>   <NA>
# 3:    id3      c   B01C   B03D   <NA>   <NA>
# 4:    id4      d   A01F   A01F   A01F   <NA>
```

---

Now to your problem.
Answer then explanation.
Answer:

```
> col_names <- tail(names(B), -2)
> B[,
     sapply(
         A,
         function (code) { pmin(1, rowSums(.SD == code, na.rm=T)) },
         simplify=F, USE.NAMES=T
      ),
      .SDcols=col_names
    ]
    A01B  A01C  A01D  A01E  A01F  A01G
   <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:     0     1     0     0     0     0
2:     0     1     1     0     0     0
3:     0     0     0     0     0     0
4:     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

**Edit**: just realised it's way easier to read if you ditch the data frame and just use a matrix of all but your first 2 columns of B! Your result will also be a matrix rather than a data frame.

```
# B[, ..col_names] if using a data.table
# B[, col_names] if using a data.frame
sapply(A, function (code) { pmin(1, rowSums(B[, ..col_names] == code, na.rm=T)) })
     A01B A01C A01D A01E A01F A01G
[1,]    0    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    1    0
```

---

Explanation:
First presume I only have one code 'A01C' and am just trying to produce the A01C column.

First make a vector of column names we want to check (everything except the first 2)

```
col_names <- tail(names(B), -2)
```

Then check if any of these columns is A01C (the `.SDcols=col_names` just selects columns 3 to 6)

```
# this is TRUE if the column has A01C in it. 
> B[, .SD == 'A01C', .SDcols=col_names]
      col3  col4  col5 col6
[1,]  TRUE    NA    NA   NA
[2,]  TRUE FALSE    NA   NA
[3,] FALSE FALSE    NA   NA
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE   NA
```

But we want to combine these to one value per row. We can do this by adding the TRUEs in each row, which returns the number of matches. `rowSums` will do this. I add `na.rm=T` to treat the NA as 0. The `.(A01C=rowSums(...))` syntax just says "make the output a column called A01C".

```
# But we wnat to condense this to one value per row.
> B[, .(A01C=rowSums(.SD == 'A01C', na.rm=T) > 0), .SDcols=col_names]
    A01C
   <num>
1:     1
2:     1
3:     0
4:     0
```

Great, so now we just have to loop over every code in `A` and do this for each.

```
> B[,
     sapply(
         A,
         function (code) { rowSums(.SD == code, na.rm=T) },
         simplify=F, USE.NAMES=T
      ),
      .SDcols=col_names
    ]
    A01B  A01C  A01D  A01E  A01F  A01G
   <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:     0     1     0     0     0     0
2:     0     1     1     0     0     0
3:     0     0     0     0     0     0
4:     0     0     0     0     3     0
```

Except note that this returns the number of matches (e.g. the A01F column row 4 has '3' rather than '1' because there are 3 A01Fs in that row). You seem to want just a 1 or 0, so we can just take the minimum of each number and 1 (or we could do a > 0 check and convert to numeric, doesn't matter). To do this we change `rowSums(...)` to `pmin(1, rowSums(...))` and get the desired result already posted above.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the column values in `B` into one column using `tidyr::unite` and then expand them into 1/0 values using `cSplit_e` from `splitstackshape`

```
result <- B %>%
 tidyr::unite(tmp, V3:V4, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
 splitstackshape::cSplit_e('tmp', sep = '_', type = 'character', fill = 0)

result

#   V1 V2       tmp tmp_A01C tmp_A01D tmp_A01F tmp_B01C tmp_B03D
#1 id1  a      A01C        1        0        0        0        0
#2 id2  b A01C_A01D        1        1        0        0        0
#3 id3  c B01C_B03D        0        0        0        1        1
#4 id4  d A01F_A01F        0        0        1        0        0
```

If there are certain values in `A` which are not present in `B` at all we can use `setdiff` to create those columns in `result`.

```
result[setdiff(unlist(A), names(result))] <- 0
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems no relationship with A? I want to return the matrix filter by if there is a value in each row in B can match the value in A. A just have one row.

Comment: @FeixiangSun Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%in%` with `apply`:

```
C <- +t(apply(B, 1, "%in%", x=A))
colnames(C) <- A
C
#  A01B A01C A01D A01E A01F A01G
#a    0    1    0    0    0    0
#b    0    1    1    0    0    0
#c    0    0    0    0    0    0
#d    0    0    0    0    1    0
```

Data:

```
A <- c("A01B", "A01C", "A01D", "A01E", "A01F", "A01G")
B <- read.table(row.names=2, text="
id1 a A01C  NA    NA    NA 
id2 b A01C A01D   NA    NA
id3 c B01C B03D   NA    NA
id4 d A01F A01F  A01F   NA")[-1]
```